# Add a count column based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to figure out how to select all data from my table, but also add an additional count column (`ticket_count`) that shows how many times the same `ticket_no` is listed in the table.

Here is my starting table:

```
|id |ticket_no|   date   |time |  item_no   |item_total|item_qty|
|---|---------|----------|-----|------------|----------|--------|
|293|   755667|2021-06-08|11:09|      367044|     45.00|       1|
|294|   755670|2021-06-08|11:09|      365751|     68.00|       1|
|295|   755672|2021-06-08|11:09|409809527273|     16.00|       1|
|296|   755672|2021-06-08|11:09|409808793105|     16.00|       1|
|297|   755672|2021-06-08|11:09|      370574|    105.00|       1|
|298|   755676|2021-06-08|11:09|409806703748|     18.95|       1|
|299|   755676|2021-06-08|11:09|      363655|     60.00|       1|
|300|   755676|2021-06-08|11:09|      369693|     68.00|       1|
|301|   755681|2021-06-08|11:09|      331621|     15.99|       1|
|302|   755681|2021-06-08|11:09|      331632|     15.99|       1|
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
|id |ticket_no|   date   |time |  item_no   |item_total|item_qty|ticket_count|
|---|---------|----------|-----|------------|----------|--------|------------|
|293|   755667|2021-06-08|11:09|      367044|     45.00|       1|           1|
|294|   755670|2021-06-08|11:09|      365751|     68.00|       1|           1|
|295|   755672|2021-06-08|11:09|409809527273|     16.00|       1|           3|
|296|   755672|2021-06-08|11:09|409808793105|     16.00|       1|           3|
|297|   755672|2021-06-08|11:09|      370574|    105.00|       1|           3|
|298|   755676|2021-06-08|11:09|409806703748|     18.95|       1|           3|
|299|   755676|2021-06-08|11:09|      363655|     60.00|       1|           3|
|300|   755676|2021-06-08|11:09|      369693|     68.00|       1|           3|
|301|   755681|2021-06-08|11:09|      331621|     15.99|       1|           2|
|302|   755681|2021-06-08|11:09|      331632|     15.99|       1|           2|
```

The best I came up with is:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(ticket_no) AS ticket_count FROM table GROUP BY ticket_no ORDER BY id ASC
```

but that keeps all the duplicate `ticket_no` rows.

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: When selected without using the DISTINCT keyword, the query should return you what you are expecting up here. Are you aiming to show the duplicate values for the ticket_no column or not show them?

Comment: I want to show duplicate values for ticket_no because I need all the other fields (id, item_no, item_total, and Item_qty) which may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either get the count in a subquery and join the two on the `ticket_id`:

```
select t.*, c.ticket_count from tab t
inner join (SELECT ticket_no, COUNT(ticket_no) AS ticket_count FROM tab GROUP BY ticket_no) c
on t.ticket_no = c.ticket_no
```

or use a window funtion:

```
select *, COUNT(ticket_no) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_no) as ticket_count from tab t
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0be9487e6c3fc7025be9ed67e0d819ed)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!